# Redirect users by role to custom pages

Tags: php, plugin-development, dashboard, wp-login-form

I have created a custom login form that will use the default action of the wordpress one.
I need to display errors on it if occurs but at the moment the user will be redirected to `wp-login.php` in case of errors. Also I want that users are redirected to specific page based on their role, I have two custom roles and I need to show different pages to each single role.

How I can accomplish this, will the `login_redirect` filter be useful if I add it in a custom plugin?

Will a custom page added to dashboard using `add_menu_page`can be displayed to user without a particular role, or there is another way to replace the default dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redirect you can do something like this.

```
function redirect_to_page() {
    global $user;

    if (in_array( 'specified_role', $user->roles ) ) {
        return '/wp-admin/post.php?post=7&action=edit';
    }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_to_page');
```